# SQL COALESCE vs. DBNull check in C#

Tags: c#, sql, performance

In my project, I have to retrieve a large amount of data from SQL and map the data to object fields; something like this:

```
cu.UnitName = dr["UnitName"].ToString().Trim();
cu.LocalId = DbUtil.RemoveNull(dr["LocalID"], "");
cu.DatabaseName = DbUtil.RemoveNull(dr["DatabaseName"], "");
cu.DatabaseServer = DbUtil.RemoveNull(dr["DatabaseServer"], "");
cu.UserName = DbUtil.RemoveNull(dr["UserName"], "");
cu.Password = DbUtil.RemoveNull(dr["Password"], "");
cu.RoleId = DbUtil.RemoveNull(dr["RoleId"], 0);
```

where `DbUtil.RemoveNull` is following (`int` version, the `string` version is similar):

```
public static int RemoveNull(object data, int defaultValue)
    {
        if (data is DBNull || data == null)
            return defaultValue;
        return int.Parse(data.ToString());
    }
```

So I wonder if SQL's `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` would do the same job faster. Did someone do similar comparison? Which way would be more efficient?

Comment: Why not do a comparison yourself?

Comment: The performance is not going to be an issue either way. You should take whatever seems more maintainable.

Comment: Try `ISNULL`. See here for reasons (it's faster): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287642/which-is-quicker-coalesce-or-isnull

Comment: If you do go down the C# route I'd recommend using String.Empty rather than "". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and-empty-string

Comment: Of course by COALESCE I meant "SQL-way" of getting rid of null values. ISNULL or COALESCE is not the question here, rather is the SQL way is faster than C# way. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

while returning data from database, you could do

```
select COALESCE (data ,defaultValue) from table
```

that would be faster, as there is no need to execute RemoveNull function from front end code

Answer (score 0):

```
cu.LocalId = dr["LocalId"] ?? "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather make use of the following statement in your sql:

> `SELECT ISNULL(value,0)`

This will always return 0 when there is a NULL. So you do not have to convert it on the code side.

Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: See my last comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

'[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)' returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments, so you will probably use `ISNULL`.

Using `ISNULL` in your database query will be much faster. Imagine you have 1m records and you invoke a C# method 1m times, that will certainly take some time to execute.

On the other hand SQL engine is optimized to work with big number of records. But this won't be flexible enough. You can't use some complex logic and easily change the default values.

Comment: See my last comment to the question.