# Best way to do a CASE where clause SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to build an SQL SP to do a query for report. It has several arguments that could be NULL or should have a value. I am using the code below. Is there another alternative way of doing this, more cleanly or more proper. I am assuming that if an Argument is Null, i would just do a 1=1 filter condition.

```
DECLARE @Arg1 VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
        @Arg2  VARCHAR(10) = NULL

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE 
(CASE WHEN (@Arg1 IS NULL) THEN
        1
    ELSE
        @Arg1 
    END) = 
    (CASE WHEN (@Arg1 IS NULL) THEN
        1
    ELSE
        Location
    END)
AND
    (CASE WHEN (@Arg2 IS NULL) THEN
        1
    ELSE
        @Arg2 
    END) = 
    (CASE WHEN (@Arg2 IS NULL) THEN
        1
    ELSE
        Sex
    END)
```

Comment: Take a look at this article. What you are doing is a type of catch all query. There can be some serious performance issues if not handled correctly. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Hi @SeanLange, i did not quite read the article properly, any tips on what should I use to handle this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is

```
where IsNull(@Arg1,Location) = Location
  and IsNull(@Arg2, Sex) = Sex
```

This is pretty much the @IFLoop answer, but `IsNull` is slightly faster than `COALESCE`.

[Which is quicker COALESCE OR ISNULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287642/which-is-quicker-coalesce-or-isnull)

---

Running the the following queries (in my machine):

```
DECLARE @ARG1 VARCHAR(50) = 'xserver_name'

select *
from sys.tables
where IsNull(@Arg1, name) = name
```

Cost: 27%

```
select *
from sys.tables
where Coalesce(@Arg1,name) = name
```

Cost 27%

```
select *
from sys.tables
where (@Arg1 is null or @Arg1 = name)
```

Cost 45%

Run and see the Execution plan please

---

But if the number of rows of the table increases, the difference disapear, because is is dominated by the table scan time:

```
select *
from sys.all_Columns
where IsNull(@Arg1, name) = name
```

Cost: 33%

```
select *
from sys.all_Columns
where Coalesce(@Arg1,name) = name
```

Cost 34%

```
select *
from sys.all_Columns
where (@Arg1 is null or @Arg1 = name)
```

Cost 33%

Comment: So can I ask regarding performance issue between the IsNull/Coalesce vs (@Arg1 is null or @Arg1 = Location)

Comment: I think the performance difference is so slightly that the table needs to be small to perceive some difference, otherwise the time spent in these function will be ridiculous compared to the table scan.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just do it like this?

```
where 
(@Arg1 is null or @Arg1 = Location)
and
(@Arg2 is null or @Arg2 = Sex)
```

Then if `@Arg1` (or 2) is null then that part of the predicate is `TRUE` and `and`'d with the next predicate.

Comment: there we go, just went with this code i saw on other SP, this one seems better. Is this the best on my case?

Comment: I don't know much about your case, but this is easier to read and more commonly used. I use this approach every time I've had this problem, and I have never needed an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, going with this

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility, even shorter, is to use [`Coalesce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
where COALESCE(@Arg1, Location) = Location
  and COALESCE(@Arg2, Sex) = Sex
```

That is, when @arg1 and @arg2 have values, use them, otherwise, otherwise use the column in question; since `Location = Location` is always true (at least when not NULL, same issue in your own code).

Comment: This was my go ahead plan but Location = Location is not a factor of perf issues?

Comment: @Sid I've just made a test, and looks like `Location = Location` is evaluated in a way different from what you thought. It's in fact very fast. The reference of column to itself can be derived by the SQL Server and the expression of `true` is return nearly immediately. The string comparison happens only when there is some argument of character-based type in the expresion.

Comment: @KingKing Should we say Location = Location is infact faster/the same comparing to NULL IS NULL ?

Comment: @Sid I think they are almost the same.

Comment: There is a serious difference, if the column on the right side is nullable, because `NULL = NULL` is not a match;  In that case, something like `COALESCE(@arg1, location, 1) = COALESCE(location, 1)` might be better, but in that case, there's not much readability improvement here, so i'd go with Dave's solution.  when it's *not* nullable, then the planner can (in principle, anyways) avoid examining the column at all.