# SQL Query Date between, if date column not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a query as follows

```
SELECT ajd.Make, ajd.Model, ajd.Filter, ajd.Notes, ajd.CatamacPartNumber, ajd.FromDate, ajd.ToDate 
  FROM ApplicationJapData ajd 
  WHERE ajd.Model LIKE '%FVR34%' 
  AND FromDate <= '20140701' AND ToDate >= '20140701'
```

What this query does is select rows based on `Model` containing certain search string, and where supplied date is between columns `FromDate` and `ToDate`.

The problem is that sometimes ToDate is `null`, because it is up to current date (For instance, `FromDate` = `1/1/2015`, and `ToDate` is `null` because it is `1/1/12` - `Present`)

So if I supply a value of 12-12-2015, I would still like to return rows if it meets the `FromDate` condition.

However, I can't use `OR` in  `FromDate <= '20140701' OR ToDate >= '20140701'`
because there might be `ToDate` of `1-6-15`, in which case it would be incorrect with supplied date of `12-12-2015`

Any help is much appreciated, and please ask if anything is unclear or needs clarifying!

Comment: Your requirement is not clear.  Are you worried about different date formats, or do you want to somehow handle `NULL` to and from dates?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Tim. I just wanted to handle Null dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AND FromDate <= '20140701' 
AND (ToDate is null OR ToDate >= '20140701')
```

Comment: Will work, but unfortunately many query optimizers still seem to struggle with OR

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger - please tell us why.

Comment: @BrendanGooden You should also read Gordon's answer which discusses another method for dealing with `NULL` dates, which might perform better if you have an index on the `ToDate` column.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Can you explain the indexing on `ToDate` ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 - not sure what you want me to tell you.  Observationally many query optimizers still have trouble with OR.  I could speculate about their inner workings, but query optimization is insanely complex and depends heavily on the DBMS.  If this works and performs well in a given situation, that's fine; I'm merely pointing out that it might not, and if not there are other options.  (And as a rule of thumb, I personally use OR as a last resort when there are multiple ways, because of what I've seen performance-wise.)

Answer (score 1):

The canonical methods are:

```
SELECT ajd.Make, ajd.Model, ajd.Filter, ajd.Notes, ajd.CatamacPartNumber, ajd.FromDate, ajd.ToDate 
FROM ApplicationJapData ajd 
WHERE ajd.Model LIKE '%FVR34%' AND
      FromDate <= '20140701' AND (ToDate >= '20140701' or ToDate IS NULL)
```

or:

```
WHERE ajd.Model LIKE '%FVR34%' AND
      FromDate <= '20140701' AND
      coalesce(ToDate, '20140701') >= '20140701'
```

Under some circumstances, you may want to pick a distant future date as the end date -- so the value is never `NULL`.  This can be beneficial in encouraging index usage on queries using the table.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to coalesce to_date with a far-future date, such as

```
SELECT ajd.Make, ajd.Model, ajd.Filter, ajd.Notes, ajd.CatamacPartNumber, ajd.FromDate, ajd.ToDate 
  FROM ApplicationJapData ajd 
 WHERE ajd.Model LIKE '%FVR34%' 
   AND FromDate <= '20140701' AND coalesce(ToDate,'99991231') >= '20140701'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement your logic would be to explicitly allow all `NULL` values in the to date:

```
SELECT ajd.Make,
       ajd.Model,
       ajd.Filter,
       ajd.Notes,
       ajd.CatamacPartNumber,
       ajd.FromDate,
       ajd.ToDate 
FROM ApplicationJapData ajd 
WHERE ajd.Model LIKE '%FVR34%' AND
      FromDate <= '20140701' AND (ToDate >= '20140701' OR ToDate IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answers above. [`IsNull` performs better than the generic `Coalesce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287642/which-is-quicker-coalesce-or-isnull) and better than having another `AND`.

```
   SELECT   ajd.Make, 
            ajd.Model, 
            ajd.Filter, 
            ajd.Notes, 
            ajd.CatamacPartNumber, 
            ajd.FromDate, 
            ajd.ToDate 
  FROM      ApplicationJapData ajd 
  WHERE     ajd.Model LIKE '%FVR34%' 
        AND FromDate <= '20140701' 
        AND IsNull(ToDate,'99991231') >= '20140701'
```